# Customizing filter dropdown

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm a newbie to DevExpress controls.

I've a boolean column(called "Valid") that is being shown in a DevExrpress GridContol in my C#/WPF application.

When  I click on the "key" icon on this column header,I see a dropdown with 4 choices namely: **(Blanks),(Non Blanks), (Checked)  and (Un Checked).**

I dont want this dropdown to show **(Blanks) and (Non Blanks)** choices.Only **(Checked)  and (Un Checked)** choices should appear.

Wondering if this is achievable at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CustomFilterPopupItems event to remove Blanks and Non Blanks option from the filter.

```
private void pivotGridControl1_CustomFilterPopupItems(object sender, DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotCustomFilterPopupItemsEventArgs e) {
            e.ShowBlanksItem.IsVisible = false;
        }
```